# Unexpected Behaviour Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I try make my own template with boot strap. I put my content in left side.
and my menu or navbar in right side.

I use this Html script: http://tokobootstrap.comuf.com/

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html lang="ms" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 7]>         <html lang="ms" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if IE 8]>         <html lang="ms" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
    <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="text/html;">
            <title>
            My Website        </title>
            <meta name="keywords" content="web developer, kl web developer, web application developer, web system developer, ecommerce, website developer, kuala lumpur developer">
            <meta name="description" content="My description of my website">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
            <link rel="canonical" href="http://localhost/baseweb/">
            <link href="http://localhost/baseweb/inc/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />    </head>
        <body><div class="container">
       <h1>Home!</h1><hr>
       <div class="col-lg-9">
          <div class="jumbotron">
              <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
              <p>...</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>

         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
           </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
              <h2>Heading</h2>
              <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
              <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
            </div>
            </div>
       </div><!-- content -->

       <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Sidebar</h3>
      </div>
                <div class="list-group">
                  <a href="http://localhost/baseweb/" class="list-group-item">
                    Home 
                  </a>
                  <a href="http://localhost/baseweb/about" class="list-group-item">About</a>

                </div>
    </div>
       </div><!-- sidebar -->
    </div><!-- container -->
    <script src="http://localhost/baseweb/inc/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://localhost/baseweb/inc/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

When in Laptop screen resolution it is normal. The content in left side and menu or navbar in righ side.

and when I try open it in mobile or small screen resolution. It's become abnormal behaviour.

I hope my menu in above from my content. but in fact.. the menu below the content.

how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show us your code ?

Comment: Please show us your code or a place we can check it out for ourselves, so we can help you :)

Comment: you can use media queries...

Comment: my Code is in http://tokobootstrap.comuf.com/ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using the offcanvas template it can show you there on how it work because probably if you utilize col-lg-9 and col-lg-3 what it would literally do is this

Desktop View
Col-lg-9 - width is kinda like 80% of scree width 
Col-lg-3 - width is kinda like 20% of scree width

Mobile View

Col-lg-9 - becomes 100% screen width due to the fact that bootstrap support responsive functionality
Col-lg-3 - becomes 100% screen width due to the fact that bootstrap support responsive functionality

Comment: Yes i can get it..So why the col-lg-3 its become below col-lg-9.?
i want the col-lg-3 is in above col-lg-9? can you help me sir. :)

Comment: because initially bootstrap 3 float its col-lg ,col-md,col-sm to the left side and since on mobile view it turns into a 100% width your col-lg-9 would take up all the width of your page and then it would line brake the col-lg-3 to the next line